# Differrence between $FC034D and #$FC034D?

Tags: assembly, 68000, easy68k

If I write the following code

```
MOVE $FC034D,A0 
MOVE #$FC034D,A1
```

Does A0 and A1 both point to the same memory location? Or is there some difference in using the `$` and the `#$`?

Comment: The former moves the value located at address FC034D into A0, the later moves the value FC034D into A1.

Comment: So having a `#` in front makes it a literal? Otherwise it's a memory address?

Comment: $ means hexadecimal.

Comment: Yes, using `#` makes it an immediate operand. The `$` means the number is interpreted as being in hexadecimal.

Comment: Thanks guys that answers my question completely.

Comment: Please consider answering questions as answers rather than comments. That way, voting on their usefulness and being able to mark them as accepted works as designed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based off of the results above. The first line

> MOVE $FC034D,A0

moves whatever value is stored in $FC034D to A0 or [A0] <-[$FC034D]

the second line

> MOVE #$FC034D,A1

takes the actual value FC034D and stores it in A1 or [A1] <- FC034D

A huge thanks to @RossRidge and @JoseManuelAbarcaRodríguez for helping me in the above comments.